# Drools OSGi integration - Apache Felix

Tags: java, osgi, drools, apache-felix

i'm trying to integrate drools engine inside an Apache Felix container.
I can't find ANY official resource regarding the installation process. The official documentation of drools 6.4.0.Final only state that drools is OSGi ready

Can someone give me useful informations ?

**What I did so far:**

I've tried integrating the OSGi bundle that is contained in the Drools zip distribution that can be downloaded from the official site. I couldn't find documentations out there neither technical release notes in the .zip file, so I started adding to my target platform (based on Apache felix) the kie-ci-osgi-6.4.0.Final.jar contained in the osgi-binaries folder.
I saw that there were lots of unresolved dependencies, so i **tryed** to manually add every jar, before giving up because I couldn't find nor understand what's was happening.

After that I tryed the same flow with [this jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-osgi-integration/6.4.0.Final). I also dowloaded with maven cli every dependencies without success

Comment: What have you already tried ? Have you any errors when you simply deploy drools bundles ? Have you tried googling "drools osgi" ?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm updating the question body. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should use Karaf (or jboss fuse wich is almost the same thing) rather than directly felix. Karaf provides dependency management that will ease uses of drools. But you can have a look at the karaf feature file for drools, wich will help you to list all depencencies. Look at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/drools/drools-karaf-features/6.4.0.Final/drools-karaf-features-6.4.0.Final-features-core.xml and https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/drools/drools-karaf-features/6.4.0.Final/drools-karaf-features-6.4.0.Final-features.xml

Comment: Hi, Apache felix is not my choiche. I develop on a company product which is built on top of felix. Anyway I will take a look at The links you provided. Nevertheless I honestly can't understand these lacks of drools documentation..they're quite frustrating and make me think I'm wasting my time! Thanks!

Comment: There is documentation about integrating drools with karaf or fuse... note that karaf is a set of bundle that can be used with any OSGi framework implementation, including felix

Comment: Sorry, but I don't need karaf. As I said, I work on a product which is based simply on the felix runtime. IMHO "OSGi ready" means that drools could be integrated on whatever implementation of OSGi I want... Equinox, knopflerfish, karaf, felix and so on.  In my case, Apache felix is a non-functional and essential requirement. So if drools OSGi integration is strongly coupled with Fuse or Karaf, then I need to evaluate other types of integration, for instance a standalone kie server with which I can communicate through REST

Comment: I'm not saying that drools osgi is tightly coupled with karaf, i'm just saying that this integration is more documented

Comment: Yes yes I understand, thank you anyway for the replies.

Comment: Hi Andrea
Did you find the info you were looking for?
I'm experiencing the same problems ...